# Canvas height to be recalculated when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, resize

A quick demo to show how my page looks with the Canvas that brakes height.
I need to make this canvas showing even when scrolling down. At the moment it calculates the height to the first windows view.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qFuDr/416/):

```
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


            //canvas is showing on my demo in Fiddle

            /**
             * drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
             * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
             */
            drawStuff(); 
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
            // do your drawing stuff here
    }
})();
```

any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact functionality that you want, but using ``position: fixed;`` keeps the canvas in the viewport regardless of scroll.

Comment: thanks, this is a simple fix!!! omg thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped. I posted an "official" version of the answer ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding `position: fixed;` to your canvas element.

**CSS**

```
canvas {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WusA/)